# How can function(x) be included in dplyr

Tags: r, tidyverse

I had a function that was built a few years ago using plyr. Now due to conflicts I want to
update to dplyr. What's the equivalent plyr::ddply(dataset, by, function(x) to dplyr? see below:

```
#Works
intervals <- function(dataset, by, model) {
# code

 ddply(dataset, by, function(x) {
#More code
}
}



#Does not work
intervals <- function(dataset, by, model) {
# code

#How to call function(x) with dplyr? I am getting an error here...
dataset %>% group_by(by) %>% function(x) {
#More code
}
}

Error in dataset %>% group_by(by) %>% function(x) { : 
  invalid formal argument list for "function"
```

Comment: Would suggest closing this one as fuller question is now at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77427918/how-to-update-to-dplyr

Answer (score 2):

```r
mt <- mutate(mtcars, rn = row_number())
res1 <- plyr::ddply(mt, ~ cyl, function(x) mutate(x, disp = disp / max(disp))) %>%
  arrange(rn)

res2 <- mt %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(disp = disp / max(disp)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(rn)

all.equal(res1, res2, check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

or perhaps more succinctly

```r
mt %>%
  mutate(disp = disp / max(disp), .by = cyl)
```

I create `rn` and subsequently `arrange` by it solely for a simpler comparison.

Comment: This partially solves the conversion problem but my function is somewhat large and I am still getting errors. Should I post my complete function here with a couple of small datasets to reproduce it?

Comment: I don't know how to inform the question without knowing what the function is doing. (I also don't treasure parsing through a large function.) If your function expects a single frame as its sole argument and then does something complicated with each of the columns, perhaps you can break your function arguments into just the columns it needs, then call it as `mutate(newx = myfunction(disp, mpg, gear))` assuming that it exports just a single column. If it returns a whole frame (and you can dismiss all columns except the grouping vars), try `mutate(myfunction(disp, mpg, gear))`.

Comment: I posted it as a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77427918/how-to-update-to-dplyr . The function is not too large (I don't think) Let me know if you want to check it out. Appreciate the effort @r2evans. You can just run it with the ddply call first (WORKS) so you can see what it produces.