# How to update to dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I had a function that was built a few years ago using plyr. Now due to conflicts I want to
update to dplyr.

I am trying to replace this one:

```
plyr::ddply(dataset, by, function(x)
```

with this one:

```
dataset %>% group_by(wk) %>% do(function(.x) { # Does not work
```

```
  library(tidyverse)
  intervals <- function(dataset, by, model){
  SEValues <- lm(Efficiency ~ PercQ, data = model) # Regression equation values and std Error
  MSValue <- anova(lm(Efficiency ~ PercQ, data = model))    # Mean-Square value

  Beta <- coef(summary(SEValues))
  StdE = Beta[,"Std. Error"]
  varA <- StdE[1]^2
  varB <- StdE[2]^2
  msquare <- MSValue$"Mean Sq"[2]
  meanQ <- mean(model$PercQ)
  n <- nrow(model)
  variance <- var(model$PercQ)
  covAB <- msquare*(- meanQ)/(var(model$PercQ)*n - 1)

  #Everything runs as expected with this ddply call
  ddply(dataset, by, function(x) { 

  #Error here while trying to use: 
  #dataset %>% group_by(wk) %>% do(function(x) {
  #dataset %>% group_by(wk) %>% do(function(.x) {  #######How to make 
  #this line work like the ddply line above?

  
    NumDays <- nrow(x)
    Week <- unique(x$wk)         
    Month <- unique(x$month)
    Year <- unique(x$year)      
    sampled <- subset(x, xd >= 0, select = c(xd, pd, td))
    daysSamp <- nrow(sampled)
    NonSampDays <- NumDays - daysSamp
    x$varPD <- with(x, (pd * (1 - td))/td + msquare * ((pd*(1 - td) + pd^2*td))/td^3)
    x <- data.frame(lapply(x, function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),0))) 
    xd <- x$xd
    pd <- x$pd
    td <- x$td
    mydf <- data.frame(xd, pd, td)
    transData <- t(mydf)
    Csequence <- lapply(seq(ncol(transData) - 1), function(x) x:(ncol(transData) - 1))
    CovSummary <- lapply(Csequence, function(.col){
      + cbind(xd=varA + transData[1, .col[1]] * covAB + transData[1, .col + 1] *
        covAB + transData[1, .col[1]] * transData[1, .col + 1] * varB,
        pd=transData[2, .col[1]] * transData[2, .col + 1],td=transData[3, .col[1]] * transData[3, .col + 1])
    })
    
    # rbind for the output
    WCovariance <- do.call(rbind, CovSummary)
    WCovariance <- cbind(WCovariance, WeekCov=WCovariance[, 'xd'] * WCovariance[, 'pd'] / WCovariance[, 'td'])
    SummedCovPiPj <- sum(WCovariance[, 'WeekCov'],na.rm=T)
    pdmean <- sum(x$pd)/daysSamp  
    Weekvariance <- var(x$pd)  
    SummedVarPD <- sum(x$varPD)  
    TotalPD <- pdmean*NumDays    
    varTotalPD <- ((1-daysSamp/NumDays)*NumDays^2/daysSamp*Weekvariance) + ((NumDays/daysSamp)*(SummedVarPD + 2*SummedCovPiPj))
    T <- qt((1-0.10/2),NumDays)  
    PlusMin <-T*varTotalPD^.5
    Lower <- TotalPD-PlusMin   
    Upper <- TotalPD+PlusMin  
    Final <- data.frame(Year,Week,NumDays,daysSamp,NonSampDays,pdmean,Weekvariance,SummedVarPD,SummedCovPiPj,TotalPD,varTotalPD,T,PlusMin,Lower,Upper)
    Final <- data.frame(lapply(Final,function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),0)))
    FinalData <- data.frame(Year,Week,daysSamp,NonSampDays,Lower,TotalPD,Upper,varTotalPD)
    FinalData <- data.frame(lapply(FinalData,function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),0)))
  }
  )
}

#Apply the intervals function to these two small datasets
Reg <- structure(list(PercQ = c(1.565, 1.94, 0.876, 1.027, 1.536, 1.536, 
2.607, 1.456, 2.16, 1.698), Efficiency = c(0.0125, 0.0213, 0.0037, 
0.006, 0.0148, 0.0162, 0.02, 0.0157, 0.0103, 0.0196)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ByWeek <- structure(list(wk = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2), month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), xd = c(0.0370098838217444, 
0.0391215970961887, 0.0409865246890313, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.015188, 
0.007513, 0.012716, 0.013962, 0.014259, 0.023553, 0.032122), 
    td = c(0.02701157274146, 0.0284158620689655, 0.0296560389182058, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0125, 0.007396, 0.010856, 0.011685, 0.011882, 
    0.018063, 0.023761), pd = c(317.308439683869, 0, 126.719553152898, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 2671.6, 3540.6976744186, 1270.35740604274, 
    1067.69362430466, 688.099646524154, 317.444499806234, 420.941879550524
    ), year = c(2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
    2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L))
 
intervals(dataset = ByWeek, by = 'wk' ,model = Reg)
```

Comment: You replaced it, and what?  There's code, but nothing explaining what's going on.

Comment: The function runs with ddply but doesnt run with dplyr. See commented code in the middle of the function.

Comment: I think this boils down to how to trying to do something like `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do((function(x) head(x))(.))` where the simple `head` function is used as a placeholder here instead of your long function. Also note that the help file at `?do` says it has been superseded and to try to use `reframe()` instead.

Comment: This question is annoyingly long -- it feels to me you are asking us to work for you instead of helping you resolve a question that you have worked to make focused and manageable. Here is a resource that might help: https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/bk01_base-functions.html#why_not_plyr

Comment: I know is long and that's why I was hesitant to post it. I posted a small portion of it and people was not understanding it. I don't want people to do the work for me. The work is already done, I just need help with a simple half a line of code.

Comment: `dataset %>% group_by(wk) %>% group_modify(function(x,...) {` looks promising but I still don't know how to implement it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get your code working again, with a few substitutions:

```r
library(tidyverse)

intervals <- function(dataset, by, model){
  SEValues <- lm(Efficiency ~ PercQ, data = model) # Regression equation values and std Error
  MSValue <- anova(lm(Efficiency ~ PercQ, data = model))    # Mean-Square value
  
  Beta <- coef(summary(SEValues))
  StdE = Beta[,"Std. Error"]
  varA <- StdE[1]^2
  varB <- StdE[2]^2
  msquare <- MSValue$"Mean Sq"[2]
  meanQ <- mean(model$PercQ)
  n <- nrow(model)
  variance <- var(model$PercQ)
  covAB <- msquare*(- meanQ)/(var(model$PercQ)*n - 1)
  
  by <- enquo(by)
  
  intervals <- function(dataset, by, model){
  SEValues <- lm(Efficiency ~ PercQ, data = model) # Regression equation values and std Error
  MSValue <- anova(lm(Efficiency ~ PercQ, data = model))    # Mean-Square value
  
  Beta <- coef(summary(SEValues))
  StdE = Beta[,"Std. Error"]
  varA <- StdE[1]^2
  varB <- StdE[2]^2
  msquare <- MSValue$"Mean Sq"[2]
  meanQ <- mean(model$PercQ)
  n <- nrow(model)
  variance <- var(model$PercQ)
  covAB <- msquare*(- meanQ)/(var(model$PercQ)*n - 1)
  
  by <- enquo(by)
  
  dataset |> 
    group_by(!!by) |> 
    group_modify(function(x, week) {

    NumDays <- nrow(x)
    Week <- week[[1]]
    Month <- unique(x$month)
    Year <- unique(x$year)      
    sampled <- subset(x, xd >= 0, select = c(xd, pd, td))
    daysSamp <- nrow(sampled)
    NonSampDays <- NumDays - daysSamp
    x$varPD <- with(x, (pd * (1 - td))/td + msquare * ((pd*(1 - td) + pd^2*td))/td^3)
    x <- data.frame(lapply(x, function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),0))) 
    xd <- x$xd
    pd <- x$pd
    td <- x$td
    mydf <- data.frame(xd, pd, td)
    transData <- t(mydf)
    Csequence <- lapply(seq(ncol(transData) - 1), function(x) x:(ncol(transData) - 1))
    CovSummary <- lapply(Csequence, function(.col){
      + cbind(xd=varA + transData[1, .col[1]] * covAB + transData[1, .col + 1] *
                covAB + transData[1, .col[1]] * transData[1, .col + 1] * varB,
              pd=transData[2, .col[1]] * transData[2, .col + 1],td=transData[3, .col[1]] * transData[3, .col + 1])
    })
    
    # rbind for the output
    WCovariance <- do.call(rbind, CovSummary)
    WCovariance <- cbind(WCovariance, WeekCov=WCovariance[, 'xd'] * WCovariance[, 'pd'] / WCovariance[, 'td'])
    SummedCovPiPj <- sum(WCovariance[, 'WeekCov'],na.rm=T)
    pdmean <- sum(x$pd)/daysSamp  
    Weekvariance <- var(x$pd)  
    SummedVarPD <- sum(x$varPD)  
    TotalPD <- pdmean*NumDays    
    varTotalPD <- ((1-daysSamp/NumDays)*NumDays^2/daysSamp*Weekvariance) + ((NumDays/daysSamp)*(SummedVarPD + 2*SummedCovPiPj))
    T <- qt((1-0.10/2),NumDays)  
    PlusMin <-T*varTotalPD^.5
    Lower <- TotalPD-PlusMin   
    Upper <- TotalPD+PlusMin  
    Final <- data.frame(Year,Week,NumDays,daysSamp,NonSampDays,pdmean,Weekvariance,SummedVarPD,SummedCovPiPj,TotalPD,varTotalPD,T,PlusMin,Lower,Upper)
    Final <- data.frame(lapply(Final,function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),0)))
    FinalData <- data.frame(Year,Week,daysSamp,NonSampDays,Lower,TotalPD,Upper,varTotalPD)
    data.frame(lapply(FinalData,function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),0)))
  }
  )
}

intervals(dataset = ByWeek, by = wk, model = Reg)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 9
#>      wk  Year  Week daysSamp NonSampDays Lower TotalPD  Upper varTotalPD
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     1  2007     1        3           4  214.   1036.  1858.    188331.
#> 2     2  2007     2        7           0  516.   9977. 19437.  24934451.
```

Comment: Thank you Andy, I checked group_modify but failed to add week. I appreciate your help!!